# Trying to have my program reject number inputs

Tags: c++

I am actually doing a homework problem and I have the program pretty much done. My only problem is when I enter a charactor or a number, it fails to reject it. Here is the problem:

Write a program to check for balancing symbols in the following languages:C++ (/* */, (), [], {}).

I have set up a list of if statements that makes sure if there is an uneven amount of symbols (/* */, (), [], {}) it will detect it. My only problem is when I enter a number it doesn't get filtered by any of my if statements (naturally) and it is passed through as a 'balanced' entry.

Back to my initial question, is there a way that i can have any 'int' detected and have it be rejected?  Here is one of my attempts to kinda give an idea of what I am trying to do:

```
if (top == int)
    {
        cout << "Invalid Entry"; \\an integer is detected
        main ();  \\due to an int input it would rout back through to start
    }
```

I am a total noob so any help or point in the right direction would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check for valid integer inputs, and just reject these:

```
 std::string input;
 while(std::cin >> input) {
      int dummy;
      std::istringstream iss(input);
      if(cin >> dummy) {
          cout << "Invalid Entry" << endl; //an integer is detected
          continue; // Read again
      }
      // ... process input
 }
```

Comment: You know what that didn't work, but that answer really helped! It has me thinking about my set up... when I get this up I will post some of the code to show how your answer helped fix it! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There's many possible solutions, but one of my favorites is to call a function that will handle it for me.

```
bool IsInteger(string line) {
    for (int i=0; i<line.size(); ++i) {
        if (!isdigit(line[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

int main() {
    string input;

    while (cin >> input) {
        if (IsInteger(input)) {
            cout << "Integer detected!" << endl;
        } else {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```